# Read all users in OU and export it to .txt

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to make a export of all users that are in the OU en are count them.
Now I create 2 different OU "mailbox only" and "users" and got a result.

Only I can't see which OU its got export out.
And export to a .txt don't work

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

Get-ADUser -searchscope OneLevel -Searchbase “OU=Users,OU=0001_Keezer,OU=JdsHosting,DC=jdsontzorgt,DC=local” -Filter * -ResultSetSize 5000 | Select Name
(Get-ADUser -searchscope OneLevel -Searchbase “OU=Users,OU=0001_Keezer,OU=JdsHosting,DC=jdsontzorgt,DC=local” -Filter * -ResultSetSize 5000 | Select Name).count


Get-ADUser -searchscope OneLevel -Searchbase “OU=MailboxOnly,OU=Users,OU=0001_Keezer,OU=JdsHosting,DC=jdsontzorgt,DC=local” -Filter * -ResultSetSize 5000 | Select Name
(Get-ADUser -searchscope OneLevel -Searchbase “OU=MailboxOnly,OU=Users,OU=0001_Keezer,OU=JdsHosting,DC=jdsontzorgt,DC=local” -Filter * -ResultSetSize 5000 | Select Name).count
```

Comment: You don't show how you were trying to output this nor do we see what you want your output to look like exactly. You need to select the properties you want to export. I can't imagine you want to export everything you are returning here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are repeating similar thing multiple times, it is good practice to create a function for that. Then you simply call your function with OU name and file name.

Function will get all users and store them to temporary variable. First line in file will be number of such users. Then it will list all user names.

```
function Export-UsersToTxt ([string]$OU,[string]$FileName) {
    $Users = Get-ADUser -SearchScope OneLevel -Searchbase $OU -Filter * -ResultSetSize 5000 
    $Users.Count | Out-File $FileName 
    $Users.Name | Out-File $FileName -Append
}

Export-UsersToTxt 'OU=Users,OU=0001_Keezer,OU=JdsHosting,DC=jdsontzorgt,DC=local' 'Users.txt'
Export-UsersToTxt 'OU=MailboxOnly,OU=Users,OU=0001_Keezer,OU=JdsHosting,DC=jdsontzorgt,DC=local' 'MailboxOnly.txt'
```

Answer (score 0):

this is 100% what I needed.
sorry for insufficient information but i'm pretty new in powershell and follow a class for this.

but thanks for the explanation I understand what you did and will try to do this is the future.